tauri with Firebase cloud messaging gettoken
I am working on the Tauri(vanilla js) Project for Windows and macOS. I am successfully able to add Firebase to our project. while getting a token for Firebase cloud messaging I am facing this NotAllowedError: Registration failed - permission denied error  I followed the official document for adding FCM. and I searched for the error on stack overflow and found the possible solution but I am not sure how to implement this in Tauri please help me how to solve this thanks. here is my Firebase code for cloud messaging and getting tokens. I am also adding logs. Thanks once again.
const auth = getAuth(app);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

async function requestPermissions() {
  
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log(permission)//1
      getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'key' }).then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log(currentToken)
        } else {
          console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);//2
      });
    }else{
      console.log(permission)
    }
  })
}

requestPermissions();

Logs.
granted//1
An error occurred while retrieving token.  NotAllowedError: Registration failed - permission denied//2

